# Software to compress files in Windows

Tags: windows, file-compression

I need a software to compress files in my Windows system. It should -

- be light weight,
- compress any type of files,
- fast,
- free,
- allow the maximum compression.

Which is a good one of my needs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The number one answer is most likely: [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

> - Packing / unpacking: 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP and WIM
> - Unpacking only: ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD, WIM, XAR and Z.

Its own file format - .7z - offers "high compression ratio with LZMA and LZMA2 compression".
You can also secure your .zip and .7z archives with AES-265 - if necessary.
Besides:

- It's fast (compressing and extracting)
- It's (mostly) open-source
- It supports 79 languages
- It integrates with Windows Explorer
- You can make self-extracting archives (.exe containing the archive)

Downloadable here: <strike>[Download](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) (latest stable version is 9.20)</strike> *[Latest stable version is 9.22, website was not updated to reflect those changes](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.22/)*

<strike>*I'll try to add other software for compressing files and folders later*</strike>

Another option is:

### ZPAQ

From [its website](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html):

> zpaq is a free and open source (GPL v3) incremental, journaling command-line archiver for Windows, Linux and Mac OS/X. Incremental means that when you back up your hard drive, for example:
>
> `zpaq add e:backup.zpaq c:\*`
>
> then only those files whose last-modified date has changed since the previous backup are added. For 100 GB of files, this typically takes about a minute, vs. an hour to create the first version. Journaling means that the archive is append-only. When you add files or directories to the archive, both the old and new versions are saved. You can recover old versions by specifying the date or version number, for example:
>
> `zpaq extract e:backup.zpaq c:\Users\Bob -to tmp -until 2013-10-30`
>
> will extract all the files and directories in c:\Users\Bob as of the last backup on or before Oct. 30, 2013 and put them in a directory named tmp.
>
> zpaq is faster and compresses better than most other popular archivers and backup programs, especially for realistic backups that have a lot of duplicate files and a lot of already compressed files.

I also found this picture:
[image: 10GB benchmark results]

#### zpaq doesn't have a windows GUI by default, but you can download one here: [Winzpaq - zpaq archiver GUI for Windows](http://winzpaq.com/)

Answer (score 3):

A very good opensource compression software is 7-Zip.

> High compression ratio in 7z format with LZMA and LZMA2 compression
>
> Supported formats:
>
> Packing / unpacking: 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP and WIM
>
> Unpacking only: ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD, WIM, XAR and Z.
>
> For ZIP and GZIP formats, 7-Zip provides a compression ratio that is **2-10 % better** than the ratio provided by PKZip and WinZip

From https://www.7-zip.org/

It is based on [LZMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Markov_chain_algorithm) algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

7-Zip

@tom's HARDWARE:

> 7-Zip is the only one of our four archiving and compression tools that’s free. It’s open source and offered under the GNU Lesser General Public License. 7-Zip fully supports the following seven compression formats: 7z, bzip2, GZIP, TAR, WIM, XZ, and ZIP. Additionally, 7-Zip can extract an additional 24 formats: ARJ, CAB, CHM, cpio, cramfs, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD, WIM, XAR, and Z.

If you're running a 64-Bit version of Windows, and want a 7-Zip right-click context menu, make sure to download the [64-Bit version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.22/7z922-x64.msi/download) on Sourceforge. The default download (in the summary tab) is a 32-Bit version.

(Compression performance/benchmark also @[tom's HARDWARE)](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/winrar-winzip-7-zip-magicrar,3436-7.html)